# Which Java framework for building social/collaborative app?

Tags: java, collaborative

I would like to get your opinion on this topic : I'd like to build some social/collaborative app : not much media sharing, but mainly tagging, collaborative text content (as wikis), user profile, tagging and some points system (digg/hackernews-like ?)

Answer (score 1):

The choice of webapp framework is generally not influenced by the problem domain of webapp that you'll be building. Some frameworks are better at certain processes, like page-flow wizards, but you couldn't really pick one on the basis of your described type of application.

The general advice holds here:

- pick the framework you're already familiar with, or
- pick one you think looks easiest, or
- pick one you want to learn.

Comment: Thank you skaffman !
I would like something with built-in features, a kind of CMS maybe.
Indeed, I'm not quite an experienced developer, and am not good at data management and conception, for example.